# Send button dont work

Tags: html, button

I have a code and it doesn't send email. Who can help me to make correct change? The button doesn't work. This is my code.

```html
<form id="contact" action="mailto:suport@radioryzer.ro" method="post">
    <center><h3>Formular de contact</h3></center>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Nume si Prenume" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Email" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Website (optional)" type="url" tabindex="4" 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Mesaj" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Email" id="contact-submit" data-submit="Se trimite...">Trimite</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a mailto to send an email via a form isn't a very reliable way to do mail sends. When it does work, it should open up the user's default mail client (if they have one installed) and compose a new email that the user will have to then send themselves. There are limitations of what you can pass along to the mail client - really just an subject and a body. If you want to format the body content, you may need to write some fancy javascript to handle that. If the user does not have a mail client, this would not work.

In addition, the support of this is browser specific. In my testing Safari did not work while Google Chrome did.

My recommended approach here is to set your action to a path on your server and handle the email sending server side. This would give you more control of how you want your messages formatted when it goes to your desired address and in addition, work more reliably since this is universally supported amongst clients ensuring a better user experience for your visitors.

If you still want to go with the mailto approach, this may help you out - [How to send an email using only HTML5 and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026898/how-to-send-an-email-using-only-html5-and-css)